# scala graph finding node with indegree 0

Tags: scala

I am using scala graph version 1.11.4 in my project for creating a Graph something like Graph(Fruit, DiEdge)(). I have a situation where I want to find the node Fruit whose in-degree is 0. I am not sure using which scala functionalities I can achieve the same? Thanks.